# Proper JSF approach

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jsf-2

I am new to EE7 and JSF but have been reading extensively. BalusC has noted many times that you should only navigate using HTTP GET or faces-redirect=true and I am trying to apply that to a design I am working on. I really have a few questions but understand they should be posted separately.

I am using all of the latest versions EE7, JSF 2.2.6, Netbeans 7.4, Maven, glassfish, etc. Here is the first question:

What is the best design approach when I have a very complicated configuration item (logged in Session scope user) that will take many pages to configure. the starting point is a list of items with the option to create, edit, delete and some application specific actions.

My understanding is there are two options:

1. Multiple pages with my backing bean controlling navigation possibly with ?faces-redirect=true
2. Stay on the same page with very large Facelet definitions, possibly made manageable using JSTL or ui:includes

Which is better?

BTW I have tried using f:param and f:viewParam but have not been able to make it work with a input field in a form on the sending page. f:viewParam finds the name but the value is null. I'm okay when the value is static. I assume this is possible but I am obviously missing something and haven;t been able to make it work with the partial examples I have found. If you are aware of one please identify the location so that I can follow it.

Comment: *BalusC has noted many times that you should only navigate using HTTP GET or faces-redirect=true* AFAIK you should do that when you want to access to specific data like viewing the details of an element displayed in a table. Looks like you want/need to build a [flow](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#730).

Comment: By flow I assume the implication is many related but independent pages, i.e. option 1 but @FlowScoped?The specific item is an event that gets created, changed and its state gets managed through its evolution. Not really a simple start and end point. Non-administrators perform actions against it.

Comment: Then looks like this object shouldn't be in session either, but saved into database or another datasource, and be updated every time some user wants to change its state.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi, it is saved in a database. My question relates to whether it is better to implement with many separate xhtml files and bean navigation or one large condition xhtml file leaving the user on the same page. It is based on a comment I saw from BalusC that he never changes page for edits. Maybe I misunderstood but the choices I identified reflect my interpretation of that comment.

Comment: Please post the link where you read this comment.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find it. If I see it again I will update this post. Anyway I think you already suggested approach 1 which is what I have begun. Seems easy enough to change so it isn't critical.